# Cameras No Longer Reporting Events

Tags: nest-device-access

Up until today at about noon EST all my cameras were reporting motion, person, etc.

Since then I have received zero events, not even a doorbell chime when I ring the doorbell.  I haven't changed any settings.

Thermostat events are still being received.

If anyone at Google is reading this... help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been  resolved.

Comment: This seems to be true for the first generation cameras, however my second generation camera is still not reporting any events, even though they show up in Google Home.